# IPv6 link-local address

Tags: routing, ipv6, ip-link-local

Can somebody explain why we can assign link-local address FE80::1 to both interfaces?
What does it give to me ?

```
R1(config)# interface g0/0
R1(config-if)# ipv6 address fe80::1 link-local
R1(config-if)# interface g0/1
R1(config-if)# ipv6 address fe80::1 link-local
```

Topology:

[image]

Comment: The keyword here is "scope".

Comment: Router advertisements for IPv6 stateless address autoconfiguration need to be sent from link-local address. I would assume that this is also a reason to assign local addresses. (see [rfc4861](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4861#section-4.2) and rfc4862)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ipv6 link-local addresses are unique only on the link and traffic is never forwarded.

Comment: is it enough to only have link local address, or does the router needs routable address too?

Comment: @Effie If you want to route traffic, you need routable addresses.

Comment: If I want to route traffic to end-systems, not the router?

Answer (score 4):

A link-local address is only used on a single link. Traffic on a link-local network is confined to that network and cannot be routed to a different network. All IPv6 interfaces use the same link-local network, so addresses on one link-local network can be the same on a different link-local network.

See RFC *[4291, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html)*:

> [2.5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291.html#section-2.5.6).
> Link-Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses
> Link-Local addresses are for use on a single link.  Link-Local addresses have the following format:
>
> ```
>     |   10     |
>     |  bits    |         54 bits         |          64 bits           |
>     +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
>     |1111111010|           0             |       interface ID         |
>     +----------+-------------------------+----------------------------+
> ```
>
> Link-Local addresses are designed to be used for addressing on a single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration,
> neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present.
> Routers must not forward any packets with Link-Local source or destination addresses to other links.